# Android sqlcipher case insensitive LIKE for unicode not working

Tags: android, icu, sqlcipher

I have sqlcipher library in my android application.
As I undertood it includes ICU localization. 
For example I have table Users with 1 row:

```
id name
1  Темп
```

I executing query `select * from Users where name like '%темп%'`
and result is empty.

So my question is how to make like case insensitive for unicode with sqlcipher? Am I missing something?

**UPD:** I've updated sqlcipher library to 3.3.1 and now case insesitive LIKE works for unicode as it should.

Comment: If you've fixed this, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated sqlcipher library to 3.3.1 and now case insensitive LIKE works for unicode as it should.

I guess there was some bug connected with this in older version.